# Android: How do you return from a setContentView?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, android-intent

For example, when I start a new Activity I can return to the previous activity with finish(). How can I return from setting a content view? Such as

```
setContentView(new example(context));
```

Now I am on my surface view. The reason I am asking is because currently when I press the back button from the surface view it exits the game entirely. (I have onDestroy methods with super.OnDestroy)

My surface view has a surfaceDestroyed method where it sets the game loop thread to false and that's it. I am assuming I need to do something here to tell it to switch its content view back to my menu?

If I am getting the context of these things wrong or just sounding stupid please inform me as to the right idea of how things work. :D

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are at all times in the scope of an Activity.  So, even though you are displaying a SurfaceView, that SurfaceView is contained by an Activity.  If there is no Activity below the current one in the stack of your application, then the back button will exit your app.  You can explicitly handle the back button though by overriding onKeyDown in your activity to perform your own conditional logic.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // This is a method I created in my Activity to execute my custom logic
        // related to the user pressing the back button
        return handleBackButton(keyCode, event);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

There's also an `onBackPressed` method defined in `Activity`, but that was introduced in api level 5, so you'll need to do onKeyDown if you're supporting Android 1.6 (api 4)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use intent.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ClassYouWantToReturn.class));
```

setContentView() won't help a lot because you will loose your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new and just learning myself, so forgive me if i miss something. But couldn't you use a boolean variable that sets the contentview based on it's state?

```
Boolean sView

if (sView = true){
setContentView(new example(context));
}
if (sView = false){
setContentView(new example(context));
}
```